# Using numba.jit on a user input string

Tags: python, numba

I'm trying to write a program that takes in a user input function as a string and does a number of calculations using that function. These calculations are done using numba.jit, and the code works if I hardcode my function, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to parse the string in such a way that I can turn it into a jitted function with nopython=True.

For example, my code runs with the function

```
@jit(nopython=True)
def f(x):
    return x*x
```

but I want to, instead, take the user input string 'x*x' and create the same function. I've tried using SymPy, but I couldn't make it play nicely with jit. Any ideas?

Comment: Is that user string supposed to be arbitrary Python code (including, say, `import os; os.system('rm -rf /')`? You can use `exec` for that. Or is it not arbitrary Python code, but arbitrary Python expressions (including, say, `__import__('os').system('rm -rf /')`)? You can use `eval` for that. If it's supposed to be only something that can be parsed by SymPy (are you actually using SymPy? is `x` expected to be a SymPy variable rather than a number or something?), show us your code and we can probably show you how to fix it. If it's supposed to be some more limited language, describe it.

Comment: Using [Sympy sympify](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#id1)  and [Sympy lambdify](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/numeric-computation.html#lambdify) together may be much simpler unless you are looking for some complex user input where `numba.jit` would give significant speed gains.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you actually want to take arbitrary Python code as user input and run it—which you usually really, really don't want to do, but let's assume here that you have a good reason…

But first: You mentioned trying to do this with SymPy. If you're actually trying to create functions out of SymPy expressions, e.g., by using `sympify` or `lambdify`—that ought to work, and if it doesn't, you need to show us your code if you want help debugging it.

But let's stop stalling and get to how you can do what you asked for, even though there's a good chance it isn't actually what you want.

---

Remember that decorators are just functions, which take a function and return another function, and you can call them normally. So, all you have to do is turn that arbitrary Python code into a function, and you can pass it to the decorator.

---

If that arbitrary Python code is just an expression, you can wrap it in a `lambda` expression, `eval` the result, and you've got a function that applies that expression:

```
lambdastr = f'lambda x: {user_string}'
lambdafunc = eval(lambdastr)
numbafunc = numba.jit(nopython=True)(lambdafunc)
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
numbafunc = numba.jit(nopython=True)(eval(f'lambda x: {user_string}'))
```

If you're thinking "But wait, `eval` is dangerous"—well, yeah, `eval` is dangerous because it evaluates arbitrary user strings as code, which is exactly what you want to do. There's no non-dangerous way to do that.

So, if your user passes you the string `x * x`, you've now got a function that squares its input, and if the user passes you the string `__import__('os').system('rm -rf /')`, you've now got a function that tries to erase your entire hard drive.

---

If you want to take a statement, you can effectively do the same same thing by wrapping it in a `def` and calling `exec`:

```
defstr = f'def __(x): {user_string}'
deffunc = exec(defstr)
numbafunc = numba.jit(nopython=True)(deffunc)
```

---

If that arbitrary Python code can be a block of statements, it's slightly more complicated by the fact that you need to deal with indentation, but that's not too hard:

```
user_lines = '\n'.join(' '+line for line in user_string.splitlines())
defstr = f'def __(x):\n{user_lines}'
deffunc = exec(defstr)
numbafunc = numba.jit(nopython=True)(deffunc)
```

Comment: The `exec` version doesn't seem to work as currently written, because `exec` doesn't return the function but puts it in the global scope instead. So you have to do `numba.jit(nopython=True)(__)`, which does seem to work.